# Could not able to connect Bluetooth in android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Im trying develop Bluetooth chat application.

When I am trying connect another device via Bluetooth getting below error :

```
 2020-08-20 22:54:28.501 3710-3729/com..btconnection I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
 2020-08-20 22:54:28.501 3710-3729/com.test.btconnection D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
 2020-08-20 22:54:31.736 3710-3710/com.test.btconnection V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@ae9591c
 2020-08-20 22:54:32.141 3710-3710/com.test.btconnection W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
 2020-08-20 22:54:38.014 3710-3849/com.test.btconnection W/BluetoothAdapter: getBluetoothService() called with no BluetoothManagerCallback
 2020-08-20 22:54:38.040 3710-3710/com.test.btconnection W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
 2020-08-20 22:54:40.868 3710-3710/com.test.btconnection I/Toast: Show toast from OpPackageName:com.test.btconnection, PackageName:com.test.btconnection
```

> MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    private TextView status;
    private Button btnConnect;
    private ListView listView;
    private Dialog dialog;
    private TextInputLayout inputLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> chatAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> chatMessages;
    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;

    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
    public static final String DEVICE_OBJECT = "device_name";

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
    private ChatController chatController;
    private BluetoothDevice connectingDevice;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> discoveredDevicesAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        findViewsByIds();

        //check device support bluetooth or not
        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }

        //show bluetooth devices dialog when click connect button
        btnConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPrinterPickDialog();
            }
        });

        //set chat adapter
        chatMessages = new ArrayList<>();
        chatAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, chatMessages);
        listView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
    }

    private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            setStatus("Connected to: " + connectingDevice.getName());
                            btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
                            break;
                        case ChatController.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            setStatus("Connecting...");
                            btnConnect.setEnabled(false);
                            break;
                        case ChatController.STATE_LISTEN:
                        case ChatController.STATE_NONE:
                            setStatus("Not connected");
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                    chatMessages.add("Me: " + writeMessage);
                    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;

                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    chatMessages.add(connectingDevice.getName() + ":  " + readMessage);
                    chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT:
                    connectingDevice = msg.getData().getParcelable(DEVICE_OBJECT);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected to " + connectingDevice.getName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg.getData().getString("toast"),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    private void showPrinterPickDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_bluetooth);
        dialog.setTitle("Bluetooth Devices");

        if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

        //Initializing bluetooth adapters
        ArrayAdapter<String> pairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        discoveredDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        //locate listviews and attatch the adapters
        ListView listView = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.pairedDeviceList);
        ListView listView2 = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.discoveredDeviceList);
        listView.setAdapter(pairedDevicesAdapter);
        listView2.setAdapter(discoveredDevicesAdapter);

        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        registerReceiver(discoveryFinishReceiver, filter);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // If there are paired devices, add each one to the ArrayAdapter
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                pairedDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        } else {
            pairedDevicesAdapter.add(getString(R.string.none_paired));
        }

        //Handling listview item click event
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

                connectToDevice(address);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        listView2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
                String info = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

                connectToDevice(address);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void setStatus(String s) {
        status.setText(s);
    }

    private void connectToDevice(String deviceAddress) {
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        BluetoothDevice device = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress);
        chatController.connect(device);
    }

    private void findViewsByIds() {
        status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status);
        btnConnect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_connect);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        inputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout);
        View btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (inputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please input some texts", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    //TODO: here
                    sendMessage(inputLayout.getEditText().getText().toString());
                    inputLayout.getEditText().setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth still disabled, turn off application!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }
        }
    }

    private void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (chatController.getState() != ChatController.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Connection was lost!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        if (message.length() > 0) {
            byte[] send = message.getBytes();
            chatController.write(send);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            android.content.Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH);
        } else {
            chatController = new ChatController(this, handler);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (chatController != null) {
            if (chatController.getState() == ChatController.STATE_NONE) {
                chatController.start();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatController != null)
            chatController.stop();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                    discoveredDevicesAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                }
            } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
                if (discoveredDevicesAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                    discoveredDevicesAdapter.add(getString(R.string.none_found));
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

> ChatController.java

```
public class ChatController {
private static final String APP_NAME = "BluetoothChatApp";
private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("8ce255c0-200a-11e0-ac64-0800200c9a66");

private final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private final Handler handler;
private AcceptThread acceptThread;
private ConnectThread connectThread;
private ReadWriteThread connectedThread;
private int state;

static final int STATE_NONE = 0;
static final int STATE_LISTEN = 1;
static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 2;
static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 3;

public ChatController(Context context, Handler handler) {
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    state = STATE_NONE;

    this.handler = handler;
}

// Set the current state of the chat connection
private synchronized void setState(int state) {
    this.state = state;

    handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE, state, -1).sendToTarget();
}

// get current connection state
public synchronized int getState() {
    return state;
}

// start service
public synchronized void start() {
    // Cancel any thread
    if (connectThread != null) {
        connectThread.cancel();
        connectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel any running thresd
    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread.cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    setState(STATE_LISTEN);
    if (acceptThread == null) {
        acceptThread = new AcceptThread();
        acceptThread.start();
    }
}

// initiate connection to remote device
public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Cancel any thread
    if (state == STATE_CONNECTING) {
        if (connectThread != null) {
            connectThread.cancel();
            connectThread = null;
        }
    }

    // Cancel running thread
    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread.cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to connect with the given device
    connectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
    connectThread.start();
    setState(STATE_CONNECTING);
}

// manage Bluetooth connection
public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice device) {
    // Cancel the thread
    if (connectThread != null) {
        connectThread.cancel();
        connectThread = null;
    }

    // Cancel running thread
    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread.cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    if (acceptThread != null) {
        acceptThread.cancel();
        acceptThread = null;
    }

    // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
    connectedThread = new ReadWriteThread(socket);
    connectedThread.start();

    // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_DEVICE_OBJECT);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable(MainActivity.DEVICE_OBJECT, device);
    msg.setData(bundle);
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    setState(STATE_CONNECTED);
}

// stop all threads
public synchronized void stop() {
    if (connectThread != null) {
        connectThread.cancel();
        connectThread = null;
    }

    if (connectedThread != null) {
        connectedThread.cancel();
        connectedThread = null;
    }

    if (acceptThread != null) {
        acceptThread.cancel();
        acceptThread = null;
    }
    setState(STATE_NONE);
}

public void write(byte[] out) {
    ReadWriteThread r;
    synchronized (this) {
        if (state != STATE_CONNECTED)
            return;
        r = connectedThread;
    }
    r.write(out);
}

private void connectionFailed() {
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("toast", "Unable to connect device");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    ChatController.this.start();
}

private void connectionLost() {
    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_TOAST);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("toast", "Device connection was lost");
    msg.setData(bundle);
    handler.sendMessage(msg);

    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
    ChatController.this.start();
}

// runs while listening for incoming connections
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket serverSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord(APP_NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        serverSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        setName("AcceptThread");
        BluetoothSocket socket;
        while (state != STATE_CONNECTED) {
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }

            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                synchronized (ChatController.this) {
                    switch (state) {
                        case STATE_LISTEN:
                        case STATE_CONNECTING:
                            // start the connected thread.
                            connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                            break;
                        case STATE_NONE:
                        case STATE_CONNECTED:
                            // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate
                            // new socket.
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            serverSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

// runs while attempting to make an outgoing connection
private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket socket;
    private final BluetoothDevice device;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        this.device = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        socket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            socket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
            }
            connectionFailed();
            return;
        }

        // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
        synchronized (ChatController.this) {
            connectThread = null;
        }

        // Start the connected thread
        connected(socket, device);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}

// runs during a connection with a remote device
private class ReadWriteThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    private final InputStream inputStream;
    private final OutputStream outputStream;

    public ReadWriteThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        this.bluetoothSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        inputStream = tmpIn;
        outputStream = tmpOut;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytes;

        // Keep listening to the InputStream
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream
                bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);

                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1,
                        buffer).sendToTarget();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                connectionLost();
                // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                ChatController.this.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // write to OutputStream
    public void write(byte[] buffer) {
        try {
            outputStream.write(buffer);
            handler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_WRITE, -1, -1,
                    buffer).sendToTarget();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            bluetoothSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Can you please me to resolve this error.
I have followed this link ([getbluetoothservice() called with no bluetoothmanagercallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15889908/getbluetoothservice-called-with-no-bluetoothmanagercallback/24229604#24229604)). I could not understand.

Comment: It is mentioned that "Since it is only a warning, I do not think you need to do anything about it."

Comment: That is not the actual issue in your case. It should be something else. None of the logs shared are errors.

Comment: I need to change UUID number ?

Comment: I have changed UUID , still getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved after changing the UUID.

private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");